# Python finding hourly list of files from date

Tags: python, list, date

I have a directory of files that I would like to loop over (dir1), where the filenames take the format:

```
20170605.000000
20170605.001000
20170605.002000
...
20170610.235000
```

I also have another directory with rather irregular times (dir2), where the filenames take the format:

```
20170604.235710
20170605.000427
20170605.093241
20170605.172221
...
20170611.000426
```

I would like to loop through the files in dir1, and then create a list from the files in dir2 that fall within the past hour of the name of the file in dir1. For example:

20170605.000000: get a list of all of the files within dir2 from 20170604.230000 - 20170605.000000
20170605.001000: get a list of all of the files within dir2 from 20170604.231000 - 20170605.001000
20170605.002000: get a list of all of the files within dir2 from 20170604.232000 - 20170605.002000

....

20170610.235000: get a list of all of the files within dir2 from 20170609.235000 - 20170610.235000

I have broken up a range of beginning and end ranges of yyyy, mm, dd, hh, mm, and seconds, but the code gets ugly very quickly. I know the datetime can be of help, but the delta seems to only operate on days, rather seconds. Is there a simpler way I am not aware of / thinking of?

Comment: Could you define for us what you mean by "get"ing the files in dir2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do something like this-

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

dir1_file_list = ['20170605.000000', '20170605.001000', '20170605.002000']
dir2_file_list = ['20170604.235710', '20170605.000427', '20170605.093241', '20170605.172221']

dir1_file_list = [datetime.strptime(f, '%Y%m%d.%H%M%S') for f in dir1_file_list]
dir2_file_list = [datetime.strptime(f, '%Y%m%d.%H%M%S') for f in dir2_file_list]

associations = dict()
for dir1_file in dir1_file_list:
    associations[str(dir1_file)] = []

    for dir2_file in dir2_file_list:
    if 0 <= (dir1_file - dir2_file).total_seconds() <= 3600: # One hour timeframe
        associations[str(dir1_file)].append(str(dir2_file))
```

Then print the dict `associations` to see the results.

Comment: Seems to be perfectly what I am looking for. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can convert your lists to `datetime` series using `pd.to_datetime()` and `pd.Series()`, then simply use a dictionary comprehension to return your desired output:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dir1 = [
'20170605.000000',
'20170605.001000',
'20170605.002000',
]

dir2 = [
'20170604.235710',
'20170605.000427',
'20170605.093241',
'20170605.172221',
]

dir1 = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(dir1), format='%Y%m%d.%H%M%S')
dir2 = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(dir2), format='%Y%m%d.%H%M%S')

retrieved = {i: [j for j in dir2 if i-timedelta(hours=1) < j < i] for i in dir1}
```

Returns:

```
{
Timestamp('2017-06-05 00:00:00'): [Timestamp('2017-06-04 23:57:10')],
Timestamp('2017-06-05 00:10:00'): [Timestamp('2017-06-04 23:57:10'), Timestamp('2017-06-05 00:04:27')],
Timestamp('2017-06-05 00:20:00'): [Timestamp('2017-06-04 23:57:10'), Timestamp('2017-06-05 00:04:27')]
}
```